# how can I change the color of weekends in datefield in flex 3.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

How can I change the color of Weekends in datefield. for example when user click on datefield, dateChooser popup. I want to show weekends (Sat, SUN) in red color in datechooser. How can I do this? I am using flex 3.5. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:DateField x="158" y="115" disabledColor="red">
    <mx:disabledDays>
        <mx:Number>0</mx:Number>
        <mx:Number>6</mx:Number>
    </mx:disabledDays>
</mx:DateField>
```

maybe this can help